# Draw a pie chart from a character list in R

Tags: r

I have some data in R that looks a little something like this:

```
data=c("a","a","a","b","b","c")
```

How can I efficiently (avoiding for loops if possible) process this data to obtain 2 new values that will look like this:

```
> vals
[1] 3 2 1
> lbls
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

So that I can draw a pie chart using:

```
pie(vals, labels=lbls)
```

**Important:** I mustn't use a solution a hard-codes "a" "b" and "c". I need a solution where can add any strings such as "d" or "e" into the data without tweaking the code.

---

For those who are curious as to what I'm trying to do: I'm trying to write a script that parses the SVN blame of a versioned file and draws a pie chart of the editor contribution. Essentially `data` is all editors of the file.

---

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you look for?

```
pie(table(data), names(table(data)))
```