# How to plot a single column of categories as a pie chart in R

Tags: r, visualization, pie-chart

I imported a CSV file with a single column of data, that has categories like the following:

```
car
truck
suv
suv
truck
suv
car
car
car
truck
suv
```

The data does not have any associated values. How can I plot this data in a pie chart?

Comment: `pie(table(df$var))` - and a more detailed how-to is in the **first** Google result for `R pie chart` - http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/pie.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw a pie chart from a character list in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19819573/draw-a-pie-chart-from-a-character-list-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should have, for example a dataframe with observations, such as the column you posted. In this case, I create a dataframe `e3` with 400 vehicles:

```
e3 <- data.frame(400)
e3 <- rep( c("car", "truck", "other", "bike", "suv"), c(60, 120, 20, 50, 150))
```

Since pie charts are especially useful for proportions, let's have a look on the proportions of our vehicles, than we will report on the graph in this case:

```
paste(prop.table(table(e3))*100, "%", sep = "")
[1] "15%"   "5%"    "30%"   "12.5%" "37.5%"
```

Then you can draw your pie chart,

```
pie(table(e3), labels = paste(round(prop.table(table(e3))*100), "%", sep = ""), 
col = heat.colors(5), main = "Vehicles proportions - n: 400")
```

[image]

and, finally, add it a legend with

```
legend("topright", legend = c("car", "truck", "other", "bike", "suv"), 
fill = heat.colors(5), title = "Categories", cex = 0.5)
```

Comment: Great demo @Worice

Comment: I am happy it has been useful to you, @rrg